# How likely are UDP packets on loopback to be delivered out of order?

Tags: udp, localhost

How likely are UDP packets on loopback to be delivered out of order?  I ask because this affects the reliability of loopback TCP sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't guarantee this, but I'd say you won't get out of order delivery of packets on the loopback interface.

The classic example of out-of-order delivery is that different packets sent between 2 hosts on the internet may travel different routes and thus be delivered out-of-order. Obviously that does not happen on the loopback interface, so unless someone on purpose programmed out-of-order behavior into it, the packets should be arrive in order.

In any case, TCP would hide the out of order delivery, with either no impact at all or with some re-transmitted packets. So in practice you would not be able to see a difference in TCP behavior on loopback either way.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/644372/reordered-and-duplicated-packets-when-using-udp-over-loopback-interface Reordered UDP packets over loopback do  actually happen, and not just "rarely". Practically, it's more likely than over a real connection.